# Highlight an item on the main navigation bar

Tags: shopify

Is there a way to only add CSS to one of the item in the menu? 
I want item which says "Tilbud" to turn green instead of black.

You can see the site here: 
https://www.sengefabriksudsalg.dk/

This is the code:

```
.nav-links {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;

    > li {
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;

        a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-style: none;
            border-color: $color-lightgreen;
            color: black;
            background-size: 200% 200%;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to top, $color-lightgreen 50%, transparent 50%);
            -webkit-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
            -moz-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
            -ms-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
            -o-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
            transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
            padding: 2rem;
        }
    }
```

If have allready tried this, but is does not work:

```
    nav.links > li > a[href$="/pages/sengetilbud"] {
  background-color: green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Is that the proper way?

```
        a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-style: none;
            border-color: $color-lightgreen;
            color: black;
            background-size: 200% 200%;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to top, $color-lightgreen 50%, transparent 50%);
            -webkit-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
            -moz-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
            -ms-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
            -o-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
            transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
            padding: 2rem;
        }
      a[href$="/pages/sengeudsalg"] {
color:green;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```